# Finding closest timestamp between dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

I have two dataframes

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test1 = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/10/2018')
test1 = pd.DataFrame(test1)
test1.rename(columns = {list(test1)[0]: 'time'}, inplace = True)


test2 = pd.date_range(start='1/5/2018', end='1/20/2018')
test2 = pd.DataFrame(test2)
test2.rename(columns = {list(test2)[0]: 'time'}, inplace = True)
```

Now in first dataframe I create column

```
test1['values'] = np.zeros(10)
```

I want to fill this column, next to each date there should be the index of the closest date from second dataframe. I want it to look like this:

```
0 2018-01-01   0
1 2018-01-02   0
2 2018-01-03   0
3 2018-01-04   0
4 2018-01-05   0
5 2018-01-06   1
6 2018-01-07   2
7 2018-01-08   3
```

Of course my real data is not evenly spaced and has minutes and seconds, but the idea is same. I use the following code:

```
def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))

for k in range(10):
    a = nearest(test2['time'], test1['time'][k]) ### find nearest timestamp from second dataframe

    b = test2.index[test2['time'] == a].tolist()[0] ### identify the index of this timestamp

    test1['value'][k] = b   ### assign this value to the cell
```

This code is very slow on large datasets, how can I make it more efficient?

P.S. timestamps in my real data are sorted and increasing just like in these artificial examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in one line, using numpy's [argmin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
test1['values'] = test1['time'].apply(lambda t: np.argmin(np.absolute(test2['time'] - t)))
```

Note that applying a lambda function is essentially also a loop. Check if that satisfies your requirements performance-wise.

---

You might also be able to leverage the fact that your timestamps are sorted and the timedelta between each timestamp is constant (if I got that correctly). Calculate the offset in days and derive the index vector, e.g. as follows:

```
offset = (test1['time'] - test2['time']).iloc[0].days
if offset < 0: # test1 time starts before test2 time, prepend zeros:
    offset = abs(offset)
    idx = np.append(np.zeros(offset), np.arange(len(test1['time'])-offset)).astype(int)
else: # test1 time starts after or with test2 time, use arange right away:
    idx = np.arange(offset, offset+len(test1['time']))
    
test1['values'] = idx
```